# Laravel Redirect does not work

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, laravel, redirect

I'll try to redirect with a message in a normal Laravel 5.2 controller but this still doesn't work.
I don't know why, because in a other controller it works.
This is the controller who's not working:
[image]

And this is the controller who's working:
[image]

Have anyone an idea why this doesn't redirect?
I haven't any errors or something. It does simply nothing.

Thank you!

Comment: Why you tagged javascript? You call this method by ajax or it's wrong tag?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
return redirect()->back()->with('message', 'Your message');
```

Or try to use `\Redirect` instead of `Redirect` if you want to use facade.

Comment: Now i have the error: Object of class Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse could not be converted to int. Is Redirect depended on the post- or get-method?

Answer (score 1):

Try use global namespace in first case

```
return \Redirect::back();
```

or use helper function

```
return redirect()->back();
```

Comment: Now i have the error: Object of class Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse could not be converted to int.
Is Redirect depended on the post- or get-method?